# How to seal a database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL database. I want it to be sealed after inserting datas so it can be unsealed by a client later.

So far, I came to that solution: export the database to a dump file, drop it, crypt the file using asymetric key (the client will get the other key).

Is there any better solution for database sealing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Are you sure this is only way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm exploring possibilities and I want to find as many as possible.
The idea is to be able to secure data and prevent it from any modification to ensure data integrity

Comment: Burn it to a write once read only CD/DVD.  Prevents change, secure in the fact it's only accessible physically. (you can encrypt it if you need to).

Comment: Perhaps provide the client with a read only connection. You can explore the privileges and permissions section of your database vendor

Comment: Whilst these comments are correct, A more full answer will only be possible if you can give details as to why you're sealing the DB and who it's against -- (*different threat models need different solutions*)